# in laravel ajax pagination with fetch API, Request does not reach controller

Tags: jquery, laravel

I rewrote codes from jQuery to js.

The below is jQuery code.
It works well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
  fetch_data(page);
 });


function fetch_data(page)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"/pagination/fetch_data?page="+page
    })
    .then(
        function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            $('#table_data').html(data);
        }
    )
}
```

The below js codes that I wrote.
It doesn't work the way I intended it to.

```
pageLinks.forEach(pageLink => {
    pageLink.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        pageNum = parseInt(pageLink.getAttribute('href').slice(-1))
        console.log(typeof(pageNum))

        url = 'pagination/fetch_data?page=' + pageNum
        // url = 'pagination?page=' + pageNum
        console.log(url)
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
        }).then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            // table_data.textContent = data
        })

    })

})
```

console.log(data) output below.

[image]

https://www.webslesson.info/2018/09/laravel-pagination-using-ajax.html
I referred to this site to create PAGINATION.

I checked if a request does reach laravel controller by using `Log::debug`,but it doesn't.

below is controller code.

```
class PaginationController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = DB::table('posts')->paginate(5);
        Log::debug('It worked out here');
        return view('pagination', compact('data'));
    }

    public function fetch_data(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $data = DB::table('posts')->paginate(5);
            Log::debug('jsRequest is received');
            return view('pagination_data', compact('data'));
        }
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake??
I guess that the mistake is in URL part.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When using fetch, the promise resolves to a response. Then, you need to call the response's `json()` method to get the actual json data. If you're returning raw html, use the `text()` function instead

```js
console.log(url)
fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    return response.json() // or response.text()
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

This way, you can check the `response` itself if you need to validate something or throw an error. If you don't need to do any of that stuff, you can simplify a bit your fetch call with arrow functions

```js
fetch(url, { method: 'GET' })
    .then(response => response.json()) // or response.text()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Since fetch uses promises, you can also write this code using `async`/`await` but only if it's inside an `async` function.

```js
pageLink.addEventListener('click', async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const pageNum = parseInt(pageLink.getAttribute('href').slice(-1));
    const url = 'pagination/fetch_data?page=' + pageNum;
    
    const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'GET' });
    const data = await response.json(); // or response.text()

    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I'm sorry for my late reply.